# PyQt5 Get the selected text content from other programs

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt4, signals-slots

I was looking at this example from PyQt4.

[Get the selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948947/get-the-selected-text-content-from-other-programs)

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, SIGNAL, SLOT
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMessageBox
import sys


class MyClipboard(QObject):

    @pyqtSlot()
    def changedSlot(self):
        if(QApplication.clipboard().mimeData().hasText()):
            QMessageBox.information(None, "Text has been copied somewhere!",
                                    QApplication.clipboard().text())


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    listener = MyClipboard()

    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    QObject.connect(QApplication.clipboard(), SIGNAL(
        "dataChanged()"), listener, SLOT("changedSlot()"))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However the signal and slots changed in PyQt5, and SIGNAL and SLOT is depreciated.
Any suggestion of transforming the PyQt4 SIGNAL and SLOT line.

```
QObject.connect(QApplication.clipboard(), SIGNAL(
    "dataChanged()"), listener, SLOT("changedSlot()"))
```

to PyQt5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent code is:

```
   QApplication.clipboard().dataChanged.connect(listener.changedSlot)
```

This is the [new-style signal and slot syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), which has completely replaced the [old-style syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html). The old-style syntax is error-prone, verbose, and is not pythonic - in particular, it does not raise an error if you get the signal signature wrong. PyQt4 still supports both syntaxes, but PyQt5 does not support it at all (and never will).

Comment: Thank you  the answer is correct, can you elaborate why we have to .connect via datachanged and not QObject like in PyQt4.

Comment: @StormShadow. I added some further information to my answer.

Comment: Thx for clarifying it.